# JMETER Error - Unable to load trust store: /var/tmp/jre1.8.0_281/lib/security/cacerts - Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, solace, solace-mq

I am trying to run a test from my linux VM and have been facing below error while making SSL connection to Solace Broker.

javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to load trust store: /var/tmp/jre1.8.0_281/lib/security/cacerts - Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException - /var/tmp/jre1.8.0_281/lib/security/cacerts (Is a directory) [Root exception is com.solacesystems.jcsmp.InvalidPropertiesException: Unable to load trust store: /var/tmp/jre1.8.0_281/lib/security/cacerts]

I am running script with below configuration in system.properties

```
java.naming.factory.initial = com.solacesystems.jndi.SolJNDIInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url = tcps://username:password@hostname
Solace_JMS_VPN = QA
Solace_JMS_Authentication_Scheme = AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE
Solace_JMS_SSL_KeyStore = var/tmp/kestore.jks
Solace_JMS_SSL_KeyStorePassword = pwd
Solace_JMS_SSL_TrustStore = /var/tmp/certs/truststore.jks
Solace_JMS_SSL_TrustStorePassword = pwd
Solace_JMS_JNDI_ConnectRetries = 1
Solace_JMS_JNDI_ClientDescription = PnV_Jmeter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably something is wrong with your JDK installation, as per [The Java Developer’s Guide to SSL Certificates](https://medium.com/@codebyamir/the-java-developers-guide-to-ssl-certificates-b78142b3a0fc) article:

> **Truststore**
>
> The truststore is a file that contains the root certificates for Certificate Authorities (CA) that issue certificates such as GoDaddy, Verisign, Network Solutions, and others.
>
> The truststore comes bundled with the JDK/JRE and is located in `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts`.
>
> The truststore is used **whenever our Java code establishes a connection over SSL.**

According to the error you're getting this `/var/tmp/jre1.8.0_281/lib/security/cacerts` is a folder while it must be the file.

So I would recommend double-checking the integrity of your JRE installation and eventually perform a clean install as it seems to be broken somehow

You might also be interested in [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter) article

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri T, it worked after i setup JAVA_HOME using JDK and then passed below arguments in cli while running test
-D javax.net.ssl.trusStore=your_JKS_filename.jks -D javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=yourJKSpassword